# Is my Bisection Search Algorithm so wrong?

Tags: python, algorithm

my apologies if I'm asking a silly question, but I'm a bit confused... 
I've been doing the MIT6.00X course at edx and one of the exercises is to use bisection search algorithm to find the secret number. It took me about 4 hours to finish the exercise (Yeah I'm a noob) but I managed to build this code:

```
numGuesses = 0
lo = 0
hi = 100
mid = (hi + lo)/2
num = raw_input( "Input a number between 0 and 100 ")
if num > 0 or num < 100:
    while mid  != num:
        print ("Is your number " + str(mid) + "?")
        userinput = raw_input( "Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")

        if userinput == 'h':
            hi = mid
            mid = (hi + lo)/2
        elif userinput == 'l':
            lo = mid
            mid = (hi + lo)/2
        elif userinput == 'c':
            print ("Game over. Your secret number was:" + str(mid))
            break
        else:
            print ("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
else:
    print ("You should use a number between 0 and 100")
```

While testing it by hand it works just fine, although in the exercise there are a few questions that don't go through mainly because the site instead of keep guessing if it's higher or lower sometimes it presses the wrong key and I fail the exercise.

After trying to change the code I wasn't able to finish the course so I've seen the answer, and this is were I did wrong, I should had use a boolean to keep the code flowing until it finds the correct number.

My question is: Is my code that wrong? Also is there any mistake I did that's preventing the site to press the correct letter? Just curious

Many thanks

Comment: I'm confused. What is "the site" that's "press[ing] the wrong key"? Is the user of this script a robot you also built named "Site", and you want to know how to make your script work around bugs in your user-robot? (If so, the answer depends on how many lasers you built into the robot.)

Comment: Your if statement can take in values greater than 100 and less than 0. You're saying "if val > 0 or val < 100 "... if val = 300 then it is greater than zero but not less than 100... since you have an or there... it will still evaluate to true. Use AND instead.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to provide better error handling for users who enter something impossible (e.g., you know hi==mid==low==49, and you ask 49, and they say "h"), you can either check that in the `if`/elif`/`elif` code and reject impossible answers, or check at the top of the `while` loop and bail out once you get into an impossible situation.

Comment: Also, it's a little weird to say "Input a number between 0 and 100" if you don't allow either 0 or 100. A programmer would expect 0 to be valid, but not 100. A normal user would probably expect either to be valid. If you remove that check, the rest of your code can successfully guess 0, but not 100.

Comment: @abarnert I'm taking an introduction course at edx.org and in the exercise after you send your code the site uses a robot to chose a few numbers and testes your code, this said robot chooses the number "8" for instance it keeps pressing the key **h** when the guess is too high and then all of suddently it randomly presses **l**.

Comment: Finally, are you really supposed to ask the user for their number, and then try to guess it after they've already told you? That's not a very impressive feat. "Show me your card, and I can guess your card in only 4 guesses!"

Comment: @FabioRosado: Well, if the robot can give you an F (or has enough lasers), you don't want to tell it that it's wrong… can you send your program to the site over and over to figure out what the pattern is? My guess is that it's just testing your error handling, but that's really just a guess.

Comment: @LeeJacobs I tried to use "or" first but the code just jumps to the first else after the user chooses a number, so it just prints ""You should use a number between 0 and 100" (I have no clue why though)

Comment: @abarnert I can see the correct code (or at least how the course want us to type it) I should had used a variable with a boolean value of False, then use "while not guessed:" as my while, use the (hi + lo)/2 after the while and then if the program guesses the course it should return the variable as **True** and the program would stop there, if not it would keep dividing the sum of low + high

Comment: Your description doesn't make any sense to me. If you do the `(hi + lo)/2` after the while loop, it'll only happen once, instead of each time through the loop. Or do you mean you were expected to do that at the top of the while loop instead of before the loop and in the `'h'` and `'l'` cases? In that case, it shouldn't make any difference at all.

Comment: But if you have the correct code: Step through exactly what it does in your failing case, and step through what your code does, and see what's different. You might want to use something like http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html to help you with the stepping-through part, or use the `pdb` debugger, or just add a bunch of `print` calls to each one and then look at the output.

Comment: @abarnert I'm sorry but I can't understand why I'm failing either... I've changed my code to look the same as the one presented to us as an answer and I keep failing this exercise so i guess that is bugged or I have to type EXACTLY what's in the answer, which defeats the propose of the exercise I belive o.O

Comment: @FabioRosado This isn't really a search algorithm. This is more of a "guess" algorithm. In reality, whats the point?

Comment: @pythondjango Like I said I'm really new to this and thought it was one because the lesson was about such, I take the point in this exercise is to make us think and practice what we learned in a different way, not really sure though. But one thing I can say for sure, this exercise made me think and search on how to solve the problem, perhaps that was the point, don't really know ^^;

Comment: @FabioRosado I understand. But I would consider a source that has you working on real world problems. If you're going to need to learn programming patterns and logic, practice those you'll someday use. I would recommend googling 'Think Python'. Happy trails.

Comment: @pythondjango: This _is_ an example of implementing a [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Performance), which is one of the faster search methods if the data is (or can be) physically or logically sorted.

Comment: @pythondjango I'm going to check your recommendation thanks! To be honest I'm trying to do everything I can get my hands on, been doing exercises at codecademy, attending to online classes at various sites as well

Comment: @FabioRosado: If you want us to explain the difference between your code and the "correct" code, you're really going to have to give us a link to that correct code. Alternatively, the exact text of the question might help. Ideally, both. Your question _does_ seem like a decent answer to the paraphrased question you've shown us, except for the error-handling difficulties described above. But obviously it's not a correct answer to the question as assigned. That could be because of the error-handling problems, or some other requirement we don't know about, but it's hard to guess.

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564050/python-stuck-on-a-guessing-games-program

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the MITx finger exercise that I just finally solved it today. here is my method:

```
print('Please think of an integers BETWEEN 0 and 100!')
#Define variable
x=100
low=0
high=x
ans=0
#Guessing code part
while ans<=x:
    print'Is your secret number:', str((low+high)/2), '?'
    s=raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly:")
    if s!='h' and s!='l' and s!='c':
        print'Sorry I did not understand your input.'
    elif s=='h':
        high=(low+high)/2
    elif s=='l':
        low=(low+high)/2
    elif s=='c':
        print'Game over. Your secret number is:', str((low+high)/2)
        break
```

Comment: May I suggest setting something like `middle = (low + high) / 2` at the top of the loop so you don't have to repeat that expression several times?

Answer (score -1):

```
lo = 0
hi = 100
mid = (hi + lo)/2
print 'Please think of a number between 0 and 100!'
while True:
    print ("Is your number " + str(mid) + "?")
    userinput = raw_input( "Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")

    if userinput == 'h':
        hi = mid
        mid = (hi + lo)/2
    elif userinput == 'l':
        lo = mid
        mid = (hi + lo)/2
    elif userinput == 'c':
        print ("Game over. Your secret number was:" + str(mid))
        break
    else:
        print ("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
```

Comment: Please try and explain your answer!