# Python- Stuck on a guessing game's program?

Tags: python

So, I've been working on this guessing game problem for a while and I am left scratching my brain for the past 2 hours trying to figure out what's wrong but I can't. I also tried searching for the solution but I don't wanna do copy & paste and I actually want to solve *my* code by myself.

Here's what I've been able to get so far:

```
start = 0
end = 100
print 'Please think of a number between 0 and 100!'
user = ''
ans = (start + end) / 2

while user != 'c':
    print ('Is your secret number ' +  str((start + end) / 2) + '?')
    user = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")
    if user == 'l':
        start = ans
    elif user == 'h':
        end = end - ans
    ans = start
print 'Game over. Your secret number was: ' + str((start + end) / 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Edit: The game should run something like this:

```
Please think of a number between 0 and 100!
Is your secret number 50?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. l
Is your secret number 75?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. l
Is your secret number 87?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. h
Is your secret number 81?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. l
Is your secret number 84?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. h
Is your secret number 82?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. l
Is your secret number 83?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. c
Game over. Your secret number was: 83
```

Comment: And what problem do you have with the code? What happens when you run it? for some input, what output would you expect, and what output do you actually get?

Comment: also, this seems to be in python 2 format, why aren't you using python3?

Comment: I am taking the Edx course on Intro to CS and programming and they're using Python 2.x, so that's why. But for my own projects, I always use Py 3.x. :)

Comment: A +1 for ''''I also tried searching for the solution but I don't wanna do copy & paste and I actually want to solve my code by myself''''.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi This will not work in Python 3. Also, how do we know that this is not some homework task in Edx? I finished Intro into CS from MITx.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Does that matter, at all? OP has a problem with a nearly complete solution, so it’s perfectly fine to ask for help.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac No, this _is_ in fact a homework task. And since it's a homework task, that's why I never asked for the direct solution or the complete source code, I was just looking for an explanation about where I was mistaken.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi: Well I cannot give you more than +1. However salute to your honesty. Cheers, keep it up!

Comment: @poke Well the honor certificates are worth less if everyone cheats :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are settings `ans = start`, thats the mistake. Since you want to solve this yourself, I will not further explain things. This is what causes your program to never decrease below 25:

```
Please think of a number between 0 and 100!
Is your secret number 50?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. h
Is your secret number 25?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. h
Is your secret number 25?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. h
Is your secret number 25?
Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. h
Is your secret number 25?
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your current code. First of all, you are never changing `ans` within the loop. You probably want to have `ans` contain the number that is the current guess. So you should set it whenever you do a guess and use it in the ouput directly. So move the `ans = (start + end) / 2` line at the beginning of the loop.

The second problem, is that you set `end = end - ans` when the guess was too high. While this works most of the times as you are using binary search and always guess in halves, it is not really what you want to do. If you want to search in the range `[start, end]` then you should set `end` to the highest number that is still available for guessing; that would be `ans - 1` when you guessed too high.

Lastly, you probably want to catch the situation where `start == end`. In this case, either you have found the number, or the user has entered some wrong stuff.

Also as a general tip, printing out intermediary results can help a lot when debugging. For example you could put a `print(start, end)` at the top of your loop to see the range you are looking at during each guess. Then you would have easily noticed, that the beginning of the range never changed.

Answer (score 0):

My solution works:

```
import random
numH = 100
numL = 0
num = random.randint(numL, numH)
print num

x = raw_input('Enter high, low or number 1: ')
while x == 'l' or x == 'h':
    if x == 'l':
        numH = num - 1
        num = random.randint(numL, numH)
        print num
        x = raw_input('Enter high, low or number 2: ')
    if x == 'h':
        numL = num + 1
        num = random.randint(numL, numH)
        print num
        x = raw_input('Enter high, low or number 2: ')  
    else:
        print 'your number is ', num
```